# Create-react-app css source-maps in development

Tags: css, webpack, source-maps, create-react-app

How can I make visible css filenames in chrome dev tools instead of `<style></style>`?

Is it possible to save the changes made in dev tools into actual css/sass files?

Comment: Don't import css files in you components. user DOM to append css with filename.

Comment: [How to save CSS changes of Styles panel of Chrome Developer Tools?](//stackoverflow.com/q/6843495)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your question title/body is a little confusing, but I'll give it a go.

> How can I make visible css filenames in chrome dev tools instead of ?

Assuming that you're wanting to see the source files versus the compiled output, this is a Chrome Dev Tools Setting. You can access that setting most easily from the Dev Tools. With Dev Tools open, you can access Settings either via `F1` or by selecting the 3-dot-stack button in the upper-right. Under `Sources`, you can turn on "Enable CSS Source Maps". [DevTool Source Map Documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/source-maps)

> Is it possible to save the changes made in dev tools into actual css/sass files?

Yep. You can use DevTool Workspaces to do this. You can read the full Workspace recommendations [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/setup-workflow).